# Cannot change panel top bar title using Gnome extension (Ubuntu 22.04.2)

Tags: 22.04, gnome-shell, gnome-shell-extension, dconf, top-bar

I am trying to change the top bar title, as follows:

I have installed the "panel date format" Gnome extension:

https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1462/panel-date-format

Then:

`~$ gnome-extensions enable panel-date-format@keiii.github.com`

returned with no error message.
Then:

```
dconf write /org/gnome/shell/extensions/panel-date-format/format "'%A %-d %B %Y %k:%M (%:z)'"
```

returned with no error; but there is no change at the top bar title.

```
~$ gnome-shell --version
GNOME Shell 42.5
```

When opening dconf-editor, it shows, under the title:

/org/gnome/shell/extensions/panel-date-format/format

```
No schema is available. A schema is what describes the use of a key, and dconf editor cannot find one associated with this key. If the application that was using this key has been uninstalled, or if this key is obsolete, you may want to erase it

Defined by: Dconf backend

Current value: %A %-d %B %Y %k:%M (%:z)
```

This was fixed according to: https://lukastrumm.com/notes/gnome-settings-schema/

```
sudo cp -v /home/user/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/panel-date-format@keiii.github.com/schemas/org.gnome.shell.extensions.panel-date-format.gschema.xml /usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/
sudo glib-compile-schemas /usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/
```

and now dconf-editor is not complaining about an error; but still, the top panel bar title is not changing!

System: Ubuntu 22.04.2; Linux 5.19.0-41-generic #42~22.04.1-Ubuntu

Comment: Sounds like a good question for the people that made the extension.